# Why does my bool value in Core Data change when I reload the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I swipe my UITableViewCell (whose objects are from Core Data) it sets the object for the cell as "read" (in code: `isRead` becomes `YES`).

This is accomplished as such:

```
- (void)swipedToMarkCellRead:(Article *)article {
     if ([article.isRead isEqualToNumber:@YES]) {
          article.isRead = @NO;
     }
     else {
          article.isRead = @YES;
     }

     NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
     NSError *error;
     [context save:&error];
}
```

However, the very next time the app loads the article is back in the unread state (or `isRead` is equal to `NO`). I made `isRead` a transient property in Core Data so whenever it's accessed I can do things to it, and I manipulate it as such:

```
- (NSNumber *)isRead {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"isRead"];
    NSNumber *isRead = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"isRead"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"isRead"];

    // If at 100% progress (finished) or it's already marked as read
    if ([self.progress intValue] >= 1 || [isRead boolValue]) {
        isRead = @YES;
    }
    else {
        isRead = @NO;
    }

    return isRead;
}
```

Is that somehow confusing it? I don't see what would be causing the change.

Comment: If you want to store the value it should not be a transient property should it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply, transient properties are not stored persistently; they are never written to the database which is why they default back to `NO`.

["Transient properties are properties that you define as part of the model, but which are not saved to the persistent store as part of an entity instance's data."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html)